# Maven building with Ant localRepository

Tags: maven, ant, repository

I'm trying to build Maven with Ant on Windows.

When running ant in folder where maven was checked out I get: 
`build.xml:105: localRepository doesn't support the "path" attribute`

Line 106 with localRepository is: `<localRepository path="${maven.repo.local}" />`

Ant output:
    Buildfile: H:\maven-3.0-SNAPSHOT\build.xml

```
clean-bootstrap:

initTaskDefs:
 [echo] Building Apache Maven ...

isMavenHomeSet:

init:
 [echo] maven.home = C:\maven-3.0-SNAPSHOT
 [echo] maven.repo.local = C:\Users\XXX/.m2/repository
 [echo] distributionId = apache-maven
 [echo] distributionName = Apache Maven
 [echo] distributionDirectory = apache-maven

prompt-maven-home-exists:

pull:

BUILD FAILED
H:\maven-3.0-SNAPSHOT\build.xml:105: localRepository doesn't support the "path"
attribute
```

Changing slashes to backslashes in `maven.repo.local` also didn't help.

Comment: A sorry what are you trying to do? Building Maven yourself ? Or did i misunderstand something.

Comment: Yes. With tutorial http://maven.apache.org/guides/development/guide-building-m2.html

Comment: I just ask: Why? Why don't you download it from maven.apache.org ? What was the purpose of building Maven yourself ?

Comment: Well, to see how building sth bigger than my students projects, looks like.

Comment: Ah ok...Have configured the environment correct? Which target did you call?

Comment: Yes, I've set M2_HOME to c:\maven-3 and added it to the PATH. I call the default target.

Comment: You have to set the M2_HOME to the version your are building which can't be maven-3 cause i assume it will be a SNAPSHOT version. This means your checkout directory must be named accordingly.

Comment: I've changed M2_HOME, however it didn't help. I updated ANT output.

Answer (score 0):

Download [maven-ant-tasks jar from maven central](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.maven%7Cmaven-ant-tasks%7C2.1.3%7Cjar) and copy to `$ANT_HOME/lib` directory.

Answer (score 0):

The following seemed to work for us although it probably depends highly on your `build.xml`.  I'm using ant version 1.9.4 for the record.

First off, the following entry in my `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` did seem to work for ant.

```
<localRepository>/some/path/.m2/repository</localRepository>
```

This wasn't a great solution however because we didn't want to change all of the developer's config files.  For the `build.xml` file, you will need to define your local repository the same way you define your `artifact:remoteRepository` lines:

```
<artifact:remoteRepository id="central" url="..."/>
<!-- add the following line after the remoteRepository definitions -->
<artifact:localRepository id="local" path="/some/path/.m2/repository"/>
```

To make the repository work for all of our build branches, we use environment variables something like:

```
<artifact:localRepository id="local" path="${env.BUILD_HOME}/.m2/repository/"/>
```

Then you would use the `local` repo the same way you do the remote repos:

```
 <remoteRepository refid="central"/>
 <!-- add the following line after the remoteRepository usages -->
 <localRepository refid="local"/>
```

We had to add it both to the `<artifact:pom` and `<artifact:dependencies` sections to get it to work.  YMMV.